# How can I derive the sufficient KKT conditions for an SDP?

Tags: kkt-conditions, semidefinite-programming

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}$Consider the following semidefinite program (SDP)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_V \quad & -\Tr(V) \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & \begin{bmatrix} AVA^T + Q - V & \lambda AVC^T \\ \lambda CVA^T & CVC^T + R \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \\
\quad & V \succeq 0
\end{aligned} \tag{1}
$$
where $A,C,Q,$ and $R$ are input matrices and $\lambda$ is a scalar parameter. The problem in $(1)$ is a lower-level problem in a bilevel program, so I'm trying to derive the sufficient Karush–Kuhn–Tucker (KKT) conditions such that some $V \succeq 0$ solves $(1)$, to eventually replace this lower-level problem with these conditions.

According to section 14.1.4 in [1], for the following SDP,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_x \quad & c^T x \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & F_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m x_iF_i \succeq 0
\end{aligned} \tag{2}
$$
where $F_0,\dots,F_m \succeq 0$, **if** strong duality holds, then the sufficient KKT conditions are:
$$
\begin{align}
F_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m x_iF_i &\succeq 0 \\
Y &\succeq 0 \\
\Tr(F_iY) &= c_i, i = 1,\dots,n \\
\left(F_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m x_iF_i\right)Y &= 0
\end{align} \tag{3}
$$
where $Y$ is the Lagrange multiplier. These conditions were derived in [1] by first deriving the Lagrangian of $(2)$, then the dual problem, and then extracting the primal feasibility, dual feasibility, and complementary slackness conditions.

I have two questions:

1. It is not clear to me if I need to check if strong duality holds in $(1)$ before attempting to derive the KKT conditions, or if the KKT conditions are sufficient by themselves for optimality.
2. Is there a straightforward way to relate the problem in $(2)$ to the problem in $(1)$ such that the KKT conditions for $(1)$ are easily derived from the conditions given in $(3)$? Or will I need to derive the Lagrangian, then the dual problem, and then extract the conditions manually?

[1] Lecture 14: Optimality Conditions for Conic Problems, Laurent El Ghaoui, EE 227A: Convex Optimization and Applications, March 6, 2012. Available: [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~elghaoui/Teaching/EE227A/lecture14.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eelghaoui/Teaching/EE227A/lecture14.pdf)

Comment: Let me get this straight, problem (1) is linear, right?

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade yes, this constraint is a linear matrix inequality in $V$.

Comment: Well, so all the KKT theory for Linear Programs are applied for your case. Besides the linearity, is there any other peculiarity of your model I am missing?

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade that is exactly my question: what are the sufficient KKT conditions for my case? The KKT conditions that I found online apply only to SDP's of the form $$\begin{aligned} \min_{x} \quad & c^T x \\ 
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & F_0 + \sum_{i=1}^m x_iF_i \succeq 0\end{aligned}$$ However, this is not exactly the form for my SDP, so I'm not sure how to apply the KKT conditions I found online to my case.

Comment: sorry, but I had to remove my previous answer, due to my wrong reasoning.

Comment: @MatheusDiógenesAndrade fair enough, I appreciate the honesty.